# AppScript: Google Calendar Remove Events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the following code that uploads my events from Google Sheet to Google Calendar. This code searches the rows that need to be synced to the calendar based on value in column E (status) `x[4]`. Events that are marked as `Pending Schedule` or `Pending Removal` will be synced to the calendar and then update the respective rows in the sheet with `Scheduled` or `Removed`.

This code runs just fine in terms of scheduling events. But when it comes to removing events it only works if the first row of the data is marked to be removed, but not on other rows. It gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteEvent' of undefined` and when I investigated the `deleteEvent` object shows as `CalendarEvent`.

Seems like the way I have written the `if()` functions is somehow not appropriate and the `else if()` does not evaluate the whole data. I have tried replacing `else if()` with another `if()` but received the same error.

[image]

```
function calendarSync2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Test Sheet')
  var settingsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar Settings');
  var calendarId = settingsSheet.getRange('B2').getValues();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var eventArray = dataSheet.getRange('A2:I').getDisplayValues();

  for (x = 0; x < eventArray.length; x++) {

    var event = eventArray[x];
    var eventName = event[1];
    var eventDate = new Date(event[0]);
    var timeZone = event[5];
    var startTime = new Date(`${event[0]} ${event[2]} ${timeZone}`); ///Used Object literals of `` combined with ${}
    var endTime = new Date(`${event[0]} ${event[3]} ${timeZone}`);
    var status = event[4]; // Used in the following comparison expression instead of filter

    if (status === 'Pending Schedule') { /// === undertakes strict comparison
      var exisEvents = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search: eventName});  // prevents creation of duplicates
      if (exisEvents.length == 0) {
        Logger.log(`timed ${eventName} scheduled for: ${startTime} till ${endTime}`);
        eventCal.createEvent(eventName, startTime, endTime);
        eventArray[x][4] = "Scheduled"; // Updates the status
      }
    } else if (status === 'Pending Removal') {
      Logger.log(`${eventName} at ${eventDate} REMOVED`)
      var returnedEvent = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search: eventName});
      var toRemove = returnedEvent[x];
      Logger.log(`returnedEvent is: ${returnedEvent}`);
      toRemove.deleteEvent();
      eventArray[x][4] = "Removed";
    }
  }
  dataSheet.getRange('A2:I').setValues(eventArray); // Overwrite the source data with the modified array
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But when it comes to removing events it only works if the first row of the data is marked to be removed, but not on other rows.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Are your logs all turning out as expected? Can you check the values of `startTime` and `endTime`?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou I checked the logs for startTime and endTime and they are working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a little bit of digging I figured I need to create another loop for removing events. so the following code:

```
else if (status === 'Pending Removal') {
      var returnedEvent = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search: eventName});
      var toRemove = returnedEvent[x];
      toRemove.deleteEvent();
      eventArray[x][4] = "Removed";
    }
```

Should be changed to:

```
else if (status === 'Pending Removal') {
      var returnedEvents = eventCal.getEventsForDay(eventDate,
{search: eventName});
      for (i = 0; i < returnedEvents.length; i++) {
        var toRemove = returnedEvents[i];
        toRemove.deleteEvent();
        eventArray[x][4] = 'Removed';
      }
    }
```